# What is partyid when getting session token during authentication?

Tags: soap, sabre, sabredav

I am following this link and i am on the first step
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/Authentication

Am stuck in first step

So I added the following code in the header:

```
 private static function getMessageHeaderXml($actionString) {
        $messageHeader = array("MessageHeader" => array(
                "_namespace" => "http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader",
                "From" => array("PartyId" => "sample.url.of.sabre.client.com"),
                "To" => array("PartyId" => "webservices.sabre.com"),
                "CPAId" => "****",
                "ConversationId" => "convId",
                "Service" => $actionString,
                "Action" => $actionString,
                "MessageData" => array(
                    "MessageId" => "1000",
                    "Timestamp" => "2001-02-15T11:15:12Z",
                    "TimeToLive" => "2001-02-15T11:15:12Z"
                )
            )
        );
        return XMLSerializer::generateValidXmlFromArray($messageHeader);
    }
```

But I'm not getting what is the party `id` and `ConversationId` .

Can some one help me what I have to pass in from to and `ConversationId`.

Comment: PartyId often is a URI to be able to say who you are. ConversationId looks like a UUID to me.

Comment: can you add more details?

Comment: Can you tell me where i can find URl and UUID ?

Comment: @Miki what detail you need i will give you

Comment: @miki just check this https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/Authentication am stuck in first step .

Comment: @Deepak I came to your question via Review queues. I don't have intent answering your question but from what I see your question is not the bet quality. If you want effort from others please add more effort from your side. Elaborate more your question, add as much details that can help others to efficiently help you. As first step watch out on punctuations if grammar bothers you as it is bothering me. :)

Comment: @miki Ok.I will take care.I have edited my question.

Comment: @Wesley De Keirsmaeker Do you know what i have to for getting partyid and convrsationid

Comment: In the tutorial: "This step assumes you have obtained the security credentials necessary to access and call SOAP-based Sabre APIs. Contact your Sabre representative for details." The Sabre representative will give you a PartyId it seems. UUID is just a random ID and even optional.

Comment: @Wesley De Keirsmaeker ok.

Answer (score 0):

PartyId is used to specify the client application that the message is being sent to or Form.

More detail information is published under the Documentation of the Service.
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/session_management/create_session/resources